# django admin inlines with GeoModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, geodjango

I have a geodjango app that has the models Map and Point. I want to be able to add Points to the map using the admin interface. The admin interface uses a GeoModelAdmin, not the default ModelAdmin. If I want to add Points inline, I have to use:

```
class PointInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Point
    extra = 1
```

I am not sure where I should indicate that I want to use the GeoModelAdmin. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just for clarification, here's the relevant part of the admin file:

```
class MapAdmin(admin.GeoModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PointInline]

admin.site.register(Map, MapAdmin)
```

I can see the inline point addition form, but i get a text area instead of an editable map.

Comment: Are you including PointInline in the parents ModelAdmin `inlines` ?

Comment: I found a django snippet that helps with this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2232/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GeoDjango: Can I use OSMGeoAdmin in an Inline in the User Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037375/geodjango-can-i-use-osmgeoadmin-in-an-inline-in-the-user-admin)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [OSMGeoAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#osmgeoadmin-intro)?