# GeoDjango: Can I use OSMGeoAdmin in an Inline in the User Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, openstreetmap, geodjango

`Profile` contains a `PointField`. I've used OSMGeoAdmin in the ProfileAdmin, here:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    model = Profile
```

But can't figure out how to use it in an inline for display in the UserAdmin. I currently have this set up as below:

```
# User Admin, with Profile attached
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'  # As only one is displayed in this view

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (
        ProfileInline,
    )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Is it possible to use class OSMGeoAdmin in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a good feature to request I guess.

As a workaround, you can take advantage of the fact that an `InlineModelAdmin` is quite similar to a `ModelAdmin`. Both extend `BaseModelAdmin`.

Inheriting from both `StackedInline` and `ModelAdmin` should not clash too much.

The only issue is that both `__init__()` methods take 2 positional arguments and call `super().__init__()` without arguments. So whatever the inheritance order, it will fail with `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent_model' and 'admin_site'`

Fortunately, the `InlineModelAdmin.__init__()` method, the one we are interested in, is not really verbose nor complex (not too much `super().__init__()` calls in cascade).

Here is what it looks like [*in Django 1.9*](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1758-L1768):

```
def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
    self.admin_site = admin_site
    self.parent_model = parent_model
    self.opts = self.model._meta
    self.has_registered_model = admin_site.is_registered(self.model)
    super(InlineModelAdmin, self).__init__()
    if self.verbose_name is None:
        self.verbose_name = self.model._meta.verbose_name
    if self.verbose_name_plural is None:
        self.verbose_name_plural = self.model._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

And here is what its parent (`BaseModelAdmin`) looks like [*in Django 1.9*](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L115-L118)

```
def __init__(self):
    overrides = FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS.copy()
    overrides.update(self.formfield_overrides)
    self.formfield_overrides = overrides
```

Now let's put it all together:

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS

# User Admin, with Profile attached
class ProfileInline(OSMGeoAdmin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'  # As only one is displayed in this view

    def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
        self.admin_site = admin_site
        self.parent_model = parent_model
        self.opts = self.model._meta
        self.has_registered_model = admin_site.is_registered(self.model)
        overrides = FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS.copy()
        overrides.update(self.formfield_overrides)
        self.formfield_overrides = overrides
        if self.verbose_name is None:
            self.verbose_name = self.model._meta.verbose_name
        if self.verbose_name_plural is None:
            self.verbose_name_plural = self.model._meta.verbose_name_plural

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (
        ProfileInline,
    )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

It's not really a satisfying solution as it requires to copy/paste some code from django, which may be different within the version of Django you use, and might be a pain to maintain when upgrading Django. However it should work until it is included in Django as a mix-in or as an `InlineModelAdmin`.

*Note: the code snippets above are taken from Django **1.9**, you should browse github tags to find the snippets corresponding to your version.*

Answer (score 7):

Since Django admin fields use widgets, you can override the widget that's automatically set for a `PointField` using [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides). In this case, you can override all `PointField` instances to use the [OSMWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets.OSMWidget) class like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OSMWidget 

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'  # As only one is displayed in this view
    formfield_overrides = {
        PointField: {"widget": OSMWidget},
    }
```

Comment: As of Django 4.0, you can now inherit [GISModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/admin/) to get OSMWidgets to display for gis fields in model admins.